# Hive DML transactions (Update/Delete) not working for subqueries

Tags: hadoop, merge, hive, dml

I know Hive/Hadoop is not meant for Update/Delete but my requirement is to update a table person20 based on the data of table person21. With advances in Hive with ORC,it supports ACID but still it doesn't look mature.

```
$ hive --version
```

### Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.6.0

The below are the detailed steps which i performed to test the Update logic.

```
CREATE TABLE person20(
  persid int,
  lastname string,
  firstname string)
CLUSTERED BY (
  persid)
INTO 1 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://hostname.com:8020/user/hive/warehouse/person20'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='true',
  'numFiles'='3',
  'numRows'='2',
  'rawDataSize'='348',
  'totalSize'='1730',
  'transactional'='true',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1489668385')
```

Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE person20 VALUES (0,'PP','B'),(2,'X','Y');
```

Select statement:

```
set hive.cli.print.header=true;

select * from person20;

persid lastname  firstname
2       X       Y
0       PP      B
```

I have another table which is replica of person20 i.e person21:

```
CREATE TABLE person21(
  persid int,
  lastname string,
  firstname string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://hostname.com:8020/user/hive/warehouse/person21'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='true',
  'numFiles'='1',
  'numRows'='2',
  'rawDataSize'='11',
  'totalSize'='13',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1489668344')
```

Insert Statement:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE person20 VALUES (0,'SS','B'),(2,'X','Y');
```

Select statement:

```
select * from person21;

persid lastname firstname
2       X1       Y
0       SS       B
```

I want to implement MERGE logic :

```
Merge into  person20 p20 USING person21 p21
ON (p20.persid=p21.persid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE set p20.lastname=p21.lastname
```

- But  Merge will not work with my version of HIVE Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.6.0.
  This would be available starting in Hive 2.2.

Other option is correlated subquery update:-

```
hive -e "set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size = 10000000; set hive.support.concurrency = true; set hive.enforce.bucketing = true; set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict; set hive.txn.manager = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager; set hive.compactor.initiator.on = true;
set hive.compactor.worker.threads = 1 ; UPDATE person20 SET lastname = (select lastname from person21 where person21.lastname=person20.lastname);"
```

- This statement is giving the below error:-

> Logging initialized using configuration in
>   jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.6.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
>   NoViableAltException(224@[400:1: precedenceEqualExpression : ( (left=
>   precedenceBitwiseOrExpression -> $left) ( ( KW_NOT
>   precedenceEqualNegatableOperator notExpr=
>   precedenceBitwiseOrExpression ) -> ^( KW_NOT ^(
>   precedenceEqualNegatableOperator $precedenceEqualExpression $notExpr)
>   ) | ( precedenceEqualOperator equalExpr= precedenceBitwiseOrExpression
>   ) -> ^( precedenceEqualOperator $precedenceEqualExpression $equalExpr)
>   | ( KW_NOT KW_IN LPAREN KW_SELECT )=> ( KW_NOT KW_IN
>   subQueryExpression ) -> ^( KW_NOT ^( TOK_SUBQUERY_EXPR ^(
>   TOK_SUBQUERY_OP KW_IN ) subQueryExpression $precedenceEqualExpression)
>   ) | ( KW_NOT KW_IN expressions ) -> ^( KW_NOT ^( TOK_FUNCTION KW_IN
>   $precedenceEqualExpression expressions ) ) | ( KW_IN LPAREN KW_SELECT
>   )=> ( KW_IN subQueryExpression ) -> ^( TOK_SUBQUERY_EXPR ^(
>   TOK_SUBQUERY_OP KW_IN ) subQueryExpression $precedenceEqualExpression)
>   | ( KW_IN expressions ) -> ^( TOK_FUNCTION KW_IN
>   $precedenceEqualExpression expressions ) | ( KW_NOT KW_BETWEEN (min=
>   precedenceBitwiseOrExpression ) KW_AND (max=
>   precedenceBitwiseOrExpression ) ) -> ^( TOK_FUNCTION
>   Identifier["between"] KW_TRUE $left $min $max) | ( KW_BETWEEN (min=
>   precedenceBitwiseOrExpression ) KW_AND (max=
>   precedenceBitwiseOrExpression ) ) -> ^( TOK_FUNCTION
>   Identifier["between"] KW_FALSE $left $min $max) )* | ( KW_EXISTS
>   LPAREN KW_SELECT )=> ( KW_EXISTS subQueryExpression ) -> ^(
>   TOK_SUBQUERY_EXPR ^( TOK_SUBQUERY_OP KW_EXISTS ) subQueryExpression )
>   );])
>           at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.noViableAlt(DFA.java:158)
>           at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:116)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceEqualExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:8651)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceNotExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9673)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceAndExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9792)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceOrExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9951)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.expression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6567)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.atomExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6791)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceFieldExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6862)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceUnaryPrefixExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7247)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceUnarySuffixExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7307)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceBitwiseXorExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7491)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceStarExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7651)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedencePlusExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7811)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.precedencePlusExpression(HiveParser.java:44550)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnAssignmentClause(HiveParser.java:44206)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.setColumnsClause(HiveParser.java:44271)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.updateStatement(HiveParser.java:44417)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1616)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1062)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:201)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:404)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:305)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1119)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1167)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1055)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1045)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:207)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:159)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:370)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:305)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:702)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) FAILED: ParseException line 1:33 **cannot recognize input near 'select'
>   'lastname' 'from' in expression specification**

**I think it doesn't support subquery. The same statement works with constants.**

```
hive -e "set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size = 10000000; set hive.support.concurrency = true; set hive.enforce.bucketing = true; set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict; set hive.txn.manager = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager; set hive.compactor.initiator.on = true;
set hive.compactor.worker.threads = 1 ; UPDATE person20 SET lastname = 'PP' WHERE  persid = 0;"
```

--This statement successfully updates the records.

**Could you please help me in finding the best strategy to perform DML/Merge operations in HIVE.**

Comment: Side note: even if Hive did support correlated subqueries for UPDATE, I'm pretty sure your subquery would not give you the expected outcome, quote: `select lastname from person21 where person21.lastname=person20.lastname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that by brute force:

- re-create table `person20` but not ACID, partitioned on a dummy col name, and with a single partition for 'dummy'
- populate `person20` and `person21`
- create work table `tmpperson20` with exactly the same structure and the same 'dummy' partition as `person20`
- `INSERT INTO tmpperson20 PARTITION (dummy='dummy') SELECT p20.persid, p21.lastname, ... FROM person20 p20 JOIN person21 p21 ON p20.persid=p21.persid`
- `INSERT INTO tmpperson20 PARTITION (dummy='dummy') SELECT * FROM person20 p20 WHERE NOT EXISTS (select p21.persid FROM person21 p21 WHERE p20.persid=p21.persid)`
- `ALTER TABLE person20 DROP PARTITION (dummy='dummy')`
- `ALTER TABLE person20 EXCHANGE PARTITION (dummy='dummy') WITH tmpperson20`
- now you can drop `tmpperson20`

Could be more tricky with an ACID table though, because of the bucketing.

---

You might also try with a procedural language that iterates on a cursor and applies single UPDATEs in a loop. Quite inefficient for large numbers of updates...

[HPL/SQL](http://www.hplsql.org/) utility is shipping with Hive 2.x, could probably be installed on top of Hive 1.x, but I never had the opportunity to try it. And the Oracle dialect feels weird on Hive...!

Or you could develop some custom Java code using a JDBC `ResultSet` and a `PreparedStatement` in a loop.